# jQuery - select all <span> elements and remove their text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

`Hello guys`, I have spent about twenty minutes searching in vain for my answer, and need your help.  There are thousands of requests for help on how to select elements with jQuery - but everyone wants to do with with some kind of condition, ie, only select an anchor with a certain ID at a certain Y position on the page.

I have a simple request.  How do I select **all** `<span>` elements on my page and remove their text?

See the thing is, I have a form, and I have `<spans>`.  When I click the Clear Button input, all fields revert back to default (of course).  But I want the `span` elements to have their text deleted.

The `<html>` on it is simple:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear form" name="Clear Button" class="clear">
```

And my jQuery:

```
/* Clear form - used to revert all Spans back to normal */
$('#Clear Button').click(function(){
        $('span').val('');

});
```

So, the Reset effect works because that's DOM/HTML.  But my jQuery is sadly broken.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?  My script is after the Button declaration, if that helps.

Comment: don't use space in the id or value or name..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is with your button selector. You are not selecting your button. Use this instead:

```
/* Clear form - used to revert all Spans back to normal */
$('input[name="Clear Button"]').click(function(){
        $('span').text('');
});
```

Or use `$('input[type="reset"]')` if that's the only one there...

Comment: Aha! My hero! That works great - but why do I have to use `text()`?  Previously, I have used `val()` to delete the text in an input..I guess this is different?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Joseph!  You've got my tick once the timer clears! =D

Answer (score 1):

Did you source the jquery.js file into your code,
and make sure when your refering to the span
instead of leaving it "" (blank) use
the function $('span').hide
Hope i helped